# How to scroll background on the Y axis?

Tags: android, bitmap

How can I scroll the background for the game I developed on the Y axis? The game contains racing cars (on an eagle viewed camera) and the background is the road that moves from up to down.

Here is example for scrolling the background from left to right on the X axis which I made before, but when I want to scroll it on the Y axis, it doesn't and I don't know how to code it.

```
<--------
//From left to right.

public void background(){ 
        backx-= 12;
        //      backx-= backgroundSpeed;
            int newFarX = backW + backx;
            // if we have scrolled all the way, reset to start
            if (newFarX <= 0) {
                backx = 0;
                // only need one draw
                canvas.drawBitmap(background, backx, 0.0f, null);
            } else {
                // need to draw original and wrap
                canvas.drawBitmap(background, backx , 0.0f , null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(background, newFarX, 0.0f, null);
            }

    }
```

Comment: How is scrolling Y and different than scrolling X?

Comment: @DeeV X is on the horizontal axis. Y is on the vertical. Although I too don't see much difference.

Answer (score 0):

X is the horizontal axis. Y is the vertical axis.

You have already created a program which allows you to scroll **left and right** which is **horizontal**.

To make it work for the **vertical** axis too, you just swap everything from X to Y and their respective **parameters**.

```
<--------
//From top to bottom.

public void background(){ 
        backy-= 12;
        //      backy-= backgroundSpeed;
            int newFarY = backW + backy;
            // if we have scrolled all the way, reset to start
            if (newFarY <= 0) {
                backy = 0;
                // only need one draw
                canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0.0f, backy, null);
            } else {
                // need to draw original and wrap
                canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0.0f, backy , null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0.0f, newFarY, null);
            }
    }
```

Checking the [**Canvas API**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html), my answer is based off of these parameters:

`drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint);`

So the changes I made:

- Changed your X *"objects"* to Y's.
- Stopped the X axis from moving by replacing **backx** and **newFarX** with **0.0f**.
- Made the Y axis move by replacing **0.0f** with **backy** and **newFarY**.

Tell me how it goes.